# Handler.postDelayed(...) does not delay the Runnable

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, runnable, android-handler, postdelayed

i've implemented an OnCompletionListener by myself which looks like this:

```
public class SongEndCompletionListener  implements OnCompletionListener{

    String nextView;
    Context actualActivity;
    int stopTime;

    public SongEndCompletionListener(Context activity, String nextView, int time) {
        this.nextView = nextView;
        actualActivity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {


            Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                        try {
                     Intent stopplay;
                     stopplay = new Intent(actualActivity,Class.forName(nextView));
                     actualActivity.startActivity(stopplay);    
                 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                 } 
            }, stopTime); 


    }
}
```

I want it to pause for stopTime seconds, but what it actually does is as soon as the audiofile ends it jumps to the next view.
Could you maybe point me towards where i am wrong or how i could delay the switch to another Activity differently?

Every hint is appreciated!

Comment: Switching the activites is not the problem, that works fine. It just switches the activity when the "song" is finished, and not stopTime milliseconds after it stopped playing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know why your Handler does not post delayed.

> **It is because your stopTime is 0.**

**You need to set a value** for "stopTime", otherwise it will be 0.
For example to delay the Runnable for one second:

```
stopTime = 1000; // milliseconds
```

Or use your Constructor:

```
public SongEndCompletionListener(Context activity, String nextView, int time) {
    this.nextView = nextView;
    actualActivity = activity;
    this.stopTime = time; // you forgot this
}
```